# Как компилировать less файлы из консоли PHPixie?

Tags: php, phpixie

> Внимание! Этот вопрос является переводом вопроса: [How to compile less
>   files via console command in
>   PHPixie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46093056/how-to-compile-less-files-via-console-command-in-phpixie)

Хочу в проекте PHPixie использовать компиляцию less-файлов для bootstrap 3.

Как это можно сделать при помощи консольной команды PHPixie?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46093056/how-to-compile-less-files-via-console-command-in-phpixie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Описано на примере PHPixie 3

1. Предварительно необходимо подключить leafo/lessphp при помощи composer.
2. Положим less-файл темы в bundles\app\assets\templates\less\theme.less

   ```
   @import "theme_header.less";
   @import "theme_footer.less";
   ....
   ```
3. Создадим класс bundles\app\src\Console\CompileLess.php следующего вида:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace Project\App\Console;

   use PHPixie\Console\Command\Config;
   use PHPixie\Slice\Data;

   /**
    * Сonsole command to compile less to css
    */
   class CompileLess extends Command
   {
       /**
        * Configure your command
        * @param Config $config
        */
       protected function configure($config)
       {
           $config->description("Compile less to css");
       }

       /**
        * @param Data $argumentData
        * @param Data $optionData
        */
       public function run($argumentData, $optionData)
       {
           $lessphp = new \lessc;

           $less_dir =$this->builder->assetsRoot()->path().'/templates/less/';
           $css_dir = $this->builder->webRoot()->path();

           $lessphp->compileFile($less_dir.'theme.less', $css_dir.'theme.css');
       }
   }
   ```
4. И пропишем его в bundles\app\src\Console.php:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace Project\App;

   class Console extends \PHPixie\DefaultBundle\Console
   {
       protected $classMap = array(
           'greet' => 'Project\App\Console\Greet',
           'compileLess' => 'Project\App\Console\CompileLess',
       );
   }
   ```
5. После этого мы можем увидеть команду в списке доступных если запустим console без параметров и запускать:

   ```
   console app:compileLess
   ```

---

Полезные ссылки:

- [документация по console](https://phpixie.com/components/console.html)
- https://habrahabr.ru/post/314314/